# Typescript 1.5 and window.event.ctrlKey

Tags: typescript, dom-events

For debugging purposes I sometimes check to see if <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is held down for special 'secret' actions. I may do this in an arbitrary function that isn't necessary an event handler itself (it may be a callback from something or it may be an event handler).

I've been using the following in typescript:

```
if (window.event.ctrlKey)
```

Suddenly now with Visual Studio 2015 RTM (I assume this is TS 1.5) this is not allowed due to `ctrlKey` not being in the `event` object anymore.

I'm not sure why and I'm more curious than anything. Is it safe to add it back? Why was it taken away?

[As an aside it turns out this probably doesn't work in Firefox anyway so I'm also looking for a complete cross platform solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add that to the interface yourself. e.g. the following code does this :

```
interface Event{
    ctrlKey : boolean;
}

if (window.event.ctrlKey){

}
```

Checkout the docs on `lib.d.ts` : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

That said its better if you use a type assertion :

```
if ((<KeyboardEvent>window.event).ctrlKey){

}
```

Checkout the docs on type assertions : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: was it removed because it wasn't 'pure' enough or some other reason. I suppose thinking about it `ctrlKey` isn't really anything to do with a pure event.

Comment: It is not on the `Event` interface ... don't know the reason why ... but it is on the KeyboardEvent interface ... perhaps it doesn't exist on mouse events?

Comment: well it used to compile `(window.event.ctrlKey)` and now it doesn't after VS2015 RTM so I kind of assumed it was removed - but I don't have an easy way of going back to compare the old interface

Comment: `assumed it was removed ` That's for sure ... I don't know the reason though

Comment: it's also on `MouseEvent`